# Fire function when HTML5 video seeks/plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to stream video using links that expire every 2 minutes.

Basically, I use this function to replace the URL, and it works great:

```
function test(){
        var videoFile = 'new.mp4';
        var $video = $('#m video');
        var curtime = $video[0].currentTime;
        videoSrc = $('source', $video).attr('src', videoFile);
        $video[0].load();
        $video[0].currentTime = (curtime);
        $video[0].play();
    }
```

The question I have is how do I fire this function every time the video starts playing/after someone seeks in it? If i fire the ok(); function using a play event then it starts a loop since the function itself causes a play event.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this in a good way?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to register the `play` event once the video has actually started `playing`. That way it will react after a pause or a seek.

If you need to disable the event on other conditions then you simply disable the `play` event (as done in the start of the `playing` function)...

```
function test(){
    var videoFile = 'trailer.mp4';
    var $video = $('#video');
    var curtime = $video[0].currentTime;
    videoSrc = $('source', $video).attr('src', videoFile);
    $video[0].load();
    $video[0].currentTime = (curtime);
    $video[0].play();
    $video.on('playing', function () {
        $video.off('play') // remove existing Play event if there is one
        console.log("Play event bound")
        $video.on('play', function () {
            console.log("Video play. Current time of videoplay: " + $video[0].currentTime );
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: How would I fire the function? Doesn't work on a on('play.. function

Comment: did you try the replacement code above? if you watch the console it triggers after the video starts playing